# How to remain on this activity(rather than going to another one), if internet connection is lost?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a very common problem which I think every android developer faces at some time. I am making an app which loads data from web-server. So internet connectivity is being used. But I have to check for internet connectivity before every call to the server. I am doing it using ConnectivityManager and it works.

My problem is actually about notifying user if the internet connectivity is lost. I want to show the user an AlertDialog box telling him about lost internet connection. Now the problem is that if user clicks on a button and a new Activity has to be started(which will load data from server), then I am not able to show him the dialog box on the calling Activity . The catch here is that I don't want to navigate to other activity if internet is not available. I just want to remain on this activity.

There are a lot of buttons on this activity and on clicking them , user can go to different activities. All I want is not to open other activity if no internet is available and show him the dialog box on this activity only. One way to do it is by checking on every button's click(in onClick method) and then notifying the user about lost internet connection . But this may be very hectic for me as there are a lot of activities and a lot of buttons in every activity.

Is there a general and efficient way to find out if this activity is being left and a new activity is being started and after finding it, showing dialog box to the user rather than moving to next activity if internet is not available.What are the best practices for handling this issue. Please help me. I am stuck on this for last 2 days. Thanx in advance.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
       case R.id.backIcon:
           navigateMenuScreen(view);
           break;
    }
 }
```

Here is how I check the internet connectivity(and it works fine):

```
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager   = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
```

This is the navigation method:

```
    public void navigateMenuScreen(View view){
    try {           
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MenuActivity.class);      
        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, 0);     
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);        
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

My question is do I have to check internet connectivity in every navigation method(there are other methods like the above one) or is there a better way?

Comment: Without code we are helpless . Show your code please.

Comment: also please keep it short, you have a better chance of recieving answers

Comment: The problem here is that if you perform the check on `Activity1`, find there's a connection and launch `Activity2`, there's no guarantee that there will still be a connection by the time that `Activity2` starts to use the connection. It's _likely_ there will be but there's no certainty.

Comment: @nandeesh : i'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Basic : So we don't have a feasible solution for this problem?

Comment: You want to determine now if a connection will be available in future, and there's no way you can possibly know that. I'm not saying you're wrong to check early - it's a good idea - but you need to account for the fact that it's _possible_ for someone to get to `Activity2` and for `Activity2` to have no connection (picture the user entering a tunnel as they push the button on `Activity1`).

Comment: @Basic: but if I open the new activity , there will be no data to show (i.e. in the listviews , textviews, imageviews etc.)

Comment: So you need to handle that situation. Maybe that means going back to the previous activity or maybe it means putting up a spinner until the connection comes back. Another way of looking at this is what happens if the connection is lost while you're downloading the data for your activity? Although it all happens very quickly, it's not instant so at some point, one of your users will hit that "window" of losing a connection when you're using it. @LazyNinja's answer is a good start, you just need to add checks for failed downloads as well and do whatever is appropriate for your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register

```
   registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, 
       new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Listen:

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
                        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network state, such 
            // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo is connected etc.
        }
    };
```

And dont forget your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanx dude. I used it and showed alert dialog when connection was lost. So now I don't have to think about activity rendering. I don't let user do anything if internet connection is lost. I just show a persistent dialog box with "Retry" button. So user has to either retry or look for his internet connectivity in Settings od device.

Answer (score 1):

On possible solution (assuming you're developing for Android 3.0+) is to use the `AsyncTaskLoader` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)). This would mean that when the user pushes a button on `Activity1`, you launch a "background" task which retrieves your data. When it's successfully downloaded the data, it can then display `Actiivty2`.

This would guarantee data by the time `Activity2` is displayed but wouldn't guarantee that `Activity2` is shown immediately (or at all, depending on how you write it)

I'm not sure this is quite what you're after but it's worth having a read.